# Implemeting GetHashCode and Equals methods for ValueObjects

Tags: c#, nhibernate

There is a passage from `NHibernate` documentation:

> Note: if you define an `ISet` of composite elements, it is very important to implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` correctly.

What does `correctly` mean there? Is it neccessary to implement those methods for all value objects in domain?

**EXTENDING MY QUESTION**

In the article *Marc* attached user *Albic* states:

> It's actually very hard to implement `GetHashCode()` correctly because, in addition to the rules Marc already mentioned, the hash code should not change during the lifetime of an object. Therefore the fields which are used to calculate the hash code must be immutable.
>
> I finally found a solution to this problem when I was working with `NHibernate`. My approach is to calculate the hash code from the ID of the object. The ID can only be set though the constructor so if you want to change the ID, which is very unlikely, you have to create a new object which has a new ID and therefore a new hash code. This approach works best with GUIDs because you can provide a parameterless constructor which randomly generates an ID.

I suddenly realized what I've got inside my `AbstractEntity` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<T> where T : AbstractEntity<T> {
    private Nullable<Int32> hashCode;
    
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Byte[] Version { get; set; }

    public override Boolean Equals(Object obj) {
        var other = obj as T;
        if(other == null) {
            return false;
        }

        var thisIsNew = Equals(this.Id, Guid.Empty);
        var otherIsNew = Equals(other.Id, Guid.Empty);

        if(thisIsNew && otherIsNew) {
            return ReferenceEquals(this, other);
        }

        return this.Id.Equals(other.Id);
    } // public override Boolean Equals(Object obj) {

    public override Int32 GetHashCode() {
        if(this.hashCode.HasValue) {
            return this.hashCode.Value;
        }

        var thisIsNew = Equals(this.Id, Guid.Empty);
        if(thisIsNew) {
            this.hashCode = base.GetHashCode();
            return this.hashCode.Value;
        }
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    } // public override Int32 GetHashCode() {
    
    public static Boolean operator ==(AbstractEntity<T> l, AbstractEntity<T> r) {
        return Equals(l, r);
    }
    public static Boolean operator !=(AbstractEntity<T> l, AbstractEntity<T> r) {
        return !Equals(l, r);
    }
} // public abstract class AbstractEntity<T>...
```

As all `components` are nested within `entities` should I then implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` for them?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correctly means that `GetHashCode` returns the same hash code for the entities that are *expected* to be equal. Because equality of 2 entities is made by comparison of that code.

On the other side, that means that for entities that are not equal, the uniqueness of hash code has to be *guaranteed*, as much as it possible.

Comment: should this be applied only to `components` in sets or to all `components` (`value objects`) in domain?

Comment: Given that GetHashCode generally represents a loss of fidelity (i.e. more data is encoded in the object than in the resultant 32-bit hash), you cannot guarantee uniqueness of a hashcode for unequal objects. Ergo, your last point is incorrect. Collisions in hashes are inevitable (unless you're hashing something carrying less than or equal 32bits of info and you cook up a perfect hash)

Comment: it depends on the *logic* of your app. So the logic is: make gethashcode return the same value for all components that in *your* system has to be recoginzed like equals. Example: if I look on specialists, doctor and driver are not equal, if I look from biology perspective they *are* equal(both humans). So depends on how *yuor application* should work.

Comment: @spender: there is no gurantee for anything in the world, my comment, hopefully, explains a target OP should looking on, to find a best decision. By the way, thanks, would refine an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) explain this well and include specific guidance on implementation for value objects. For value objects, Equals is true if the objects are the same type and the public and private fields are equal. However, this explanation applies to framework value types and you are free to create your own Equals by overriding it.

GetHashCode has two rules that must be followed:

> - If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not
>     compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two object do not
>     have to return different values.
> - The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state
>     that determines the return value of the object's Equals method. Note
>     that this is true only for the current execution of an application,
>     and that a different hash code can be returned if the application is
>     run again.